# IOT Edge for Linux on Windows (eflow) - nested VM deployement - proxy settings - corporate firewall

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

My team is working on achieving following:

1. Sending telemetry data from OPC Server to Azure Iot Hub.
2. The environment has restricted internet, so we opened required urls and ports (outbound).
3. OPC Server has no internet, so we made a Windows Virtual Machine on same environment.
4. This Windows Virtual Machine has IoT Edge for Linux on Windows (EFLOW) deployed on it.
5. We planned to send telemetry data using OPC Publisher Module to IoT Hub.

Helping Microsoft Article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-configure-proxy-support?view=iotedge-1.4

The planned architecture is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obwCe.png)

Unfortunately, we are experiencing issues while achieving above. I am attaching logs.
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Starting Azure IoT Edge Daemon
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Version - 1.4.20
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Obtaining Edge device provisioning data...
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Identity Service.
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Starting service...
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Version - dev build
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Detected HTTPS proxy server http://123.45.67.89:8080/
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Provisioning starting. Reason: Startup
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Updated device info for myEdgeDevice.
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Provisioning complete.
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Identity reconciliation started. Reason: Startup
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Keys Service.
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Starting service...
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Version - dev build
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Loaded libaziot-keys with version 0x02010000
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - Starting server...
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "402"}
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:26 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:26Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 1 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 2 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [WARN] - Network not available for Identity reconciliation. Using offline backup from last run.
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting server...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- POST /identities/device?api-version=2020-09-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "identityd.sock", "content-length": "16"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Device is myEdgeDevice on myIOThub.azure-devices.net
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Initializing module runtime...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Using runtime network id azure-iot-edge
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Successfully initialized module runtime
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- POST /keypair?api-version=2020-09-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "61"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Certificates Service.
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting service...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Version - dev build
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting server...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- GET /certificates/aziot-edged-ca?api-version=2020-09-01 {"host": "certd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Using existing Edge CA certificate
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- GET /certificates/aziot-edged-ca?api-version=2020-09-01 {"host": "certd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-certd[14179]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Certificate aziot-edged-ca will be auto-renewed. Next renewal at 2024-03-06T13:02:07+00:00.
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Stopping all modules...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - All modules stopped
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Detecting if device information has changed...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Device information has not changed
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting management API...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting workload API...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting image garbage collection task...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Starting watchdog with 60 second period...
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - Watchdog checking Edge runtime status
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- PUT /identities/modules/$edgeAgent?api-version=2020-09-01&type=aziot {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "identityd.sock", "content-length": "40"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "402"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:30 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:30Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 1 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 2 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [INFO] - !!! Hub client error
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [INFO] - --> 404 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: 2023-12-26T18:19:34Z [WARN] - Error in watchdog: Failed to update $edgeAgent identity: Hub client error
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: caused by: error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:34 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-edged[14160]: caused by: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:35 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:35Z [INFO] - <-- POST /identities/device/reprovision?api-version=2020-09-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "identityd.sock", "content-length": "16"}
Dec 26 18:19:35 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:35Z [INFO] - Provisioning starting. Reason: Api
Dec 26 18:19:35 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:35Z [INFO] - Updated device info for myEdgeDevice.
Dec 26 18:19:35 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:35Z [INFO] - Provisioning complete.
Dec 26 18:19:35 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:35Z [INFO] - Identity reconciliation started. Reason: Api
Dec 26 18:19:36 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:36Z [INFO] - <-- GET /key/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Dec 26 18:19:36 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:36Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:36 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:36Z [INFO] - <-- POST /sign?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-type": "application/json", "host": "keyd.sock", "content-length": "402"}
Dec 26 18:19:36 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-keyd[14164]: 2023-12-26T18:19:36Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Dec 26 18:19:36 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:36Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 1 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:39 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:39Z [WARN] - Failed to send HTTP request (attempt 2 of 2): error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:39 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:39Z [INFO] - !!! Hub client error
Dec 26 18:19:39 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:39Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: error trying to connect: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:39 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:39Z [INFO] - !!! caused by: unexpected EOF
Dec 26 18:19:39 WINDOWSVM-EFLOW aziot-identityd[14162]: 2023-12-26T18:19:39Z [INFO] - --> 404 {"content-type": "application/json"}

We tried below:

1. Sending telemetry data from OPC Server to Azure Iot Hub.
2. The environment has restricted internet, so we opened required urls and ports (outbound).
3. OPC Server has no internet, so we made a Windows Virtual Machine on same environment.
4. This Windows Virtual Machine has IoT Edge for Linux on Windows (EFLOW) deployed on it.
5. We planned to send telemetry data using OPC Publisher Module to IoT Hub.

We expected stable connection between EFLOW and Iot Hub

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be issues with the connectivity
Firstly verify that the Windows Virtual Machine (WINDOWSVM-EFLOW) has the necessary outbound network connectivity to reach Azure IoT Hub.
make sure that the required URLs and ports for Azure IoT Hub are open.

Since you mentioned a restricted internet environment with a proxy, make sure that the proxy configuration is correctly set up on the Windows Virtual Machine. check the proxu settings too, kindly double check these as these might be the cause,

Try to use debugging to find the issue

```html
sudo iotedge check
sudo iotedge list
sudo iotedge logs <module-name>
```

Even after doing all of these still if it doesn't work, I recommend contacting azure support, they will assist this issue better. below link takes you directly to the support req page just fill in the details and hopefully it works.

https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/NewSupportRequestV3Blade/callerWorkflowId/fa2e194f-ac47-4741-aad8-1cdd80fcfee1/callerName/Microsoft_Azure_Support%2FHelpAndSupportOverview.ReactView

Comment: Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
-----------------------------
× host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub AMQP port - Error
    Could not connect to myIOThub.azure-devices.net : could not complete TLS handshake
× host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub HTTPS / WebSockets port - Error
    Could not connect to myIOThub.azure-devices.net : could not complete TLS handshake
× host can connect to and perform TLS handshake with iothub MQTT port - Error
    Could not connect to myIOThub.azure-devices.net : could not complete TLS handshake

Comment: Hi Usman, as i have said earlier in the answer its better to raise a support request this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the Azure IoT Certificate you are using on your virtual machine is current? It's possible that an expired cert could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks @theturkishdeveloper for looking into the matter. Can you tell me more details regarding verifying IoT Certificate on VM. Please note that this is EFLOW VM on a Windows VM (nested virtualization) with proxy settings.

Looking Forward!

Kr,
Usman Bin Imran